# Jquery selected option with condition

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel

Im currently making a dropdown with value is passed by table RA's ID, with condition like this.

```
ID   External
1    false
2    false
3    true
```

how to check if this ID external == true show another form:input.

is there any idea ?

here's my html code so far :

```
<div class="form-group">
   <label>RECRUITMENT AGENCY:</label>
      {!! Form::select('recruitment_agency_id', $recruitmentAgencyList, null, array('id' => 'recruitment_agency', 'class' => 'form-control')) !!}
</div>

<div class="form-group referral_by" style="display: none;">
   <label>REFERRAL BY:</label>
      {!! Form::text('referral_by', null, array('class' => 'form-control referral_by')) !!}
</div>
```

Comment: What code you have tried yet ?

Comment: What is your html? MySQL table does not return `true` and `false`. It returns `1` or `0`

Comment: I've tried jquery onchange if selected option .... show form. But how if selected option with condition. im confused.

Comment: @EddyTheDove updated thread, yup i know it..

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

when you inpsect element on browser your select box html should look like this.

```
<select id="ddl" onchange="checktruefalse()">
        <option value="false">1</option>
        <option value="false">2</option>
        <option value="true">3</option>
</select>
```

and here you can add your condition:

```
function checktruefalse() {
    if ($("#ddl").val() == "true") {
        alert("true...!!");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
try this:
Without any java script frameworks  you can access the value

<select id="select" onchange="myFunction(this)">
<option value="true">1</option>
 <option value="true">2</option>
<option value="false">3</option>
<option value="true">4</option>
</select>




var myFunction = function (item){
alert(item.value);
}
```